# Sorting CListView in yii

Tags: php, yii

Please consider this:

```
class User extends CActiveRecord
{
    ...
    public function relations()
    {
        return array(
            ...    
            'articleCount' => array(self::STAT, 'Article', 'userid'),
            ...    
            );
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, I need to create a `$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider(...)` to feed a `CListView` widget to which I want add `articleCount` to the property `sortableAttributes` so that I can sort User records according to the number of articles the user is the author for.

What are the most convenient method? what are the other alternatives?

Comment: Ha, it seems you know where you are going.

Comment: No, I googled enough but I could not find any clear solution

Comment: I suppose what I meant was your question was what's the most convenient method.  Meaning you could code it to work, but didn't know what would be most efficient.  I'm not with holding an answer or anything.

Comment: I believe that there at least one solution. I stopped my trials when I saw this thread http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/13281-cgridview-filter-sort-on-stat-relation/ . I decided to stop research and ask this question here in stackoverflow. Sorry if my English is not good

Comment: Your English is just fine my man.  I'll see what I can find.

Comment: I cross linked that on the yii forum.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, it took me a while, but I finally got it figured out. ;)

First, make sure you still have the same STAT relation you mention in your question.

Then, in your search() method where you are building your CDbCriteria for the CActiveDataProvider, do something like this:

```
public function search() {
  $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
  $criteria->select = 't.*, IFNULL( count(article.id), 0) as articleCount';
  $criteria->join = 'LEFT JOIN article ON article.userid = t.id';
  $criteria->group = 't.id';
  // other $criteria->compare conditions

  $sort = new CSort();
  $sort->attributes = array(
    'articleCount'=>array(
      'asc'=>'articleCountASC',
      'desc'=>'articleCountDESC',
    ),
    '*', // add all of the other columns as sortable
  );

  return new CActiveDataProvider(get_class($this), array(
    'criteria'=>$criteria,
    'sort'=>$sort,
    'pagination'=> array(
      'pageSize'=>20,
    ),
  ));
}
```

Then, in your View where you output your CGridView, do this like so:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
  'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
  'columns'=>array(
    'articleCount',
    // other columns here
  )
)); ?>
```

This works, I tested it (although I did not use the exact same names, like 'article', but the basic idea should work :) I did add some bonus features so it works better (like the IFNULL magic) but most of the credit goes to this Yii forum post:
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/7061-csort-and-selfstat-to-sort-by-count/

I hope this helps! They should add better support for this though, so you don't need to make these tricky SELECT statements. Seems like something that should 'just work', I would file an 'enhancement' request in the [Yii bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/list).