# PHP - Yii Sorting and filtering not working on rating based column

Tags: php, yii

I have Yii based web application and I'm displaying articles information in CGridView. One of CGridView column displays overall rating for each article as 5 stars.(Each article is rated by users)

Issue is that after displaying 5 stars rating for the article YII's built in sorting and filtering is removed. Requirement is to sort based on rating. I have searched but unable to figure out how to  do fix it. Any help or guidance appreciated. I call a function to calculate  rating in CGridView.

Following is the CGridView code.

```
<?php
    $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'customer-sites-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'title',
    array('name'=>'author_id',  'value'=>'$data->author->name'),  
    array(
            "header" => "Rating",
            "type" => "raw",
            "value"=>function($data){
            $ratings=$data->ratingToString($data->id);
            return '<div class="star-rating"    
                  id="rating1result'.$ratings['roundedrating'].'"   
         style="background-position:0 -'.$ratings['roundedrating2'].'px; float:left;">
                <div class="star"></div>
                <div class="star"></div>
                <div class="star"></div>
                <div class="star"></div>
                <div class="star"></div></div>';
            },
        ),
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
 ),

 ));  ?>
```

----- Edit-------------

ArticleRating.php

```
     return array(
        'article' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Article', 'article_id'),
 );
```

Article.php

```
    return array(
      'articleRating' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ArticleRating', 'article_id'),
   );
```

Comment: As you really want to sort based on an aggregate value (being the average rating), [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5616529/3012385) should help you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `rating` is a field in the table, adding the following should do:

```
array(
    'header'=>'Rating',
    'type'=>'raw',
    'value'=>function($data) {...},
    'name'=>'rating', //this is the important part!
),
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. rating is not field in table but there is another table for article ratings. here I display overall(average) rating.

Comment: 5 stars with rating are displayed in front of every article

Comment: Oh ... Well, you can also sort by related fields. Care to tell me how the relation is called? I'll update my answer then.

Comment: yes I am able to sort by related fields (those are other r filed like author name. but for this filtering is disappeared. I am going to add relations in amoment

Comment: Ah. So there's no distinct rating value but a set of ratings? That's making things complicated ...

Comment: yes each user can rate an article based (1 - 5 stars) and is saved in separate table. Articles gridview shows overall rating for that particular  article.